# How to change background color of react bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to change background color of react bootstrap modal popup.

my Modal code is -

```
<Modal
    show={this.state.show}
    onHide={this.handleClose}
    dialogClassName="modal-90w public-profile-modal-class"
    size='lg'
    aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
>
```

So how to change it ?

Comment: customize the '.modal-backdrop' style.

Comment: but this will change background of all modal .. I want to change only a particular modal

Comment: Add a custom class to a dialog using 'dialogClassName' this props. ".modal-90w public-profile-modal-class .modal-backdrop { background-color: red }"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to update modal backdrop you could use CSS like:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: green;
}
```

If you want to change modal background then use:

```
<Modal className="my-modal" show={show}>
```

and define in CSS:

```
.my-modal .modal-content {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I want to change background color of modal popup

Comment: @AnuragMishra - Just updated code according to your requirement.

Comment: but this will change background of all modal .. I want to change only a particular modal

Comment: I have defined a class `my-modal` and css is applied in respect to that modal. This will not change for all modals only for modals using the class `my-modal`

Answer (score 9):

You need to appy `CSS` to `modal-content` class to change `background-color`.

Add a class name to your modal where you want to apply background color,

```
<Modal
    show={this.state.show}
    onHide={this.handleClose}
    dialogClassName="modal-90w public-profile-modal-class"
    size='lg'
    aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
    className="special_modal" //Add class name here
>
```

Use that class name to apply `CSS`

```
.special_modal .modal-content{
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-goldstine-vi5py?fontsize=14)

Comment: but this will change background of all modal .. I want to change only a particular moda

Comment: In that case you can apply a special className to that modal and apply CSS to that className.

Comment: So how can I do that ?

Comment: @AnuragMishra, check the Demo.

Answer (score 1):

In the tag itself add: `style={{ background: 'red' }}`

```
<Modal
  size="lg"
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
  centered
  style={{ background: 'red' }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Modal.body>
    <div className="modal-background-color">
       //Your content
    </div>
</Modal.body>
```

in your css add like:

```
.modal-background-color{
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default color is white. I found a way to change the color and also you can make it transparent, that is:

```
.modal-content { background-color: transparent !important;}
```

Just paste this property in your css file and you can also give other colors instead of transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
<Modal
show={this.state.show}
onHide={this.handleClose}
dialogClassName="modal-90w public-profile-modal-class"
size='lg'
aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
  <ModalBody style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
   //your content
  </ModalBody>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Modal
      {...props}
      size="lg"
      centered
      onHide={() => props.setModalShow(false)}
      backdropClassName='' // this one for backdrop
      contentClassName="bg-transparent border-0" // this one for content
    >
....
</Modal>
```